# What is the difference between declaring a variable outside of loop and declaring static inside loop?

Tags: programming

These are two ways I can hold a variable outside of loop (or any function).

First, I can declare it with global scope outside of loop:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

int count = 0;

void loop()
{
    Serial.println(count);
    count++;

    delay(250);
}
```

I can also declare it static inside the loop:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    static int count = 0;

    Serial.println(count);
    count++;

    delay(250);
}
```

What difference, if any, will this make?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most basic difference is of scope.

In the first case, you are declaring a global variable. It is a variable that is accessible in every scope after its definition.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void inc();
int count = 0;

void loop()
{
    Serial.println(count);
    count++;

    inc();

    delay(500);
}

void inc() //Can edit the value of count
{
  count=count+1;
};
```

In the second case, you are declaring a static variable with local scope. The variable will persist for the entire program run similar to global variables, but will be accessible only in the code block it is declared in. This is the same example, with only one change. `count` is now declared as a static variable inside `loop`.

```
void inc();

void loop()
{
    static int count = 0;
    Serial.println(count);
    count++;

    inc();

    delay(500);
}
```

This will not compile as the function `inc()` does not have access to `count`.

Global variables, however seemingly useful, come with some pitfalls. These can even cause damage when it comes to writing programs that can interact with the physical surroundings. This a very basic example of something that is quite likely to happen, as soon as programs start getting larger. A function may inadvertently change the state of a global variable.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void another_function();
int state=0;

void loop()
{
    //Keep toggling the state
    Serial.println(state);
    delay(250);
    state=state?0:1;

    //Some unrelated function call
    another_function();
}

void another_function()
{
  //Inadvertently changes state
  state=1;

}
```

Such cases are very hard to debug. *This* type of problem however, can easily be detected, by simply using a static variable.

```
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
void another_function();

void loop()
{
    static int state=0;

    //Keep toggling the state
    Serial.println(state);
    delay(250);
    state=state?0:1;

    //Some unrelated function call
    another_function();
}

void another_function()
{
  //Results in a compile time error. Saves time.
  state=1;

}
```

Answer (score 5):

From a functional perspective, both versions generate the same result, since in both cases the value of `count` is stored between the executions of the `loop()` (either because it is a global variable or because it is marked as `static` and therefore keeps its value).

So the decision which to choose come down to following arguments:

1. Generally, in computer science, it is encouraged to keep your variables as local as possible in terms of **scope**. This usually results in much clearer code with less side-effects and reduces chances of someone else using that global variable screwing up your logic. E.g. in your first example, other logic areas might change the `count` value, whereas in the second, only that particular function `loop()` can do so.
2. Global and static variables always occupy **memory**, where as locals only do when they are in scope. In your above examples that makes no difference (since in one you use a global, in the other a static variable), but in bigger and more complex programs it might and you could save memory using non-static locals.
   *However*: If you have a variable in a logic area that is executed very often, consider making it either static or global, since
   otherwise you loose a tiny bit of performance each time that logic
   area is entered, since it takes a bit of time to allocate the memory
   for that new variable instance. You need to find a balance between memory load and performance.
3. Other points such as better layout for **static analysis** or **optimization** by the compiler might also come into play.
4. In some special scenarios, there might be issues with the unpredictable initialization order of static elements (not sure about that point, compare this [link](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=nt8h6685309s1vv0voea1rbkd5&topic=74180.msg559158#msg559158) though).

Source: [Similar thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=i4sdu9bn0f8u2jekn5tl5pbeo1&topic=74180.msg559208#msg559208) on arduino.cc

Comment: Re-entrancy should never be an issue on Arduino since it doesn't support concurrency.

Comment: True. That was more of a general point, but indeed not relevant for Arduino. I removed that bit.

Comment: A static variable declared inside a scope will always exist and use the same space as a global variable! In the OP code, the only difference is what code can access the variable. In scipe static wil be accessible within the same scope.

Comment: @jfpoilpret That of course is true, and I see that the respective part in my answer was a bit misleading. Fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Both variables are static - they persist for the entire execution session. The global is visible to any function if it declares - not defines - the global, or if the function follows the definition in the same compilation unit (file + includes).

Moving the definition of `count` to inside of a function both limits its scope of visibility to the nearest enclosing set of `{}`es, and gives it function invocation lifetime (it is created and destroyed as the function is entered and exited). Declaring it `static` as well gives it execution session lifetime it exists from the start to the end of the execution session, persisting across function invocations.

BTW: be cautious about using initialized statics within a function, as I have seen some versions of the gnu compiler get this wrong. An automatic variable with an initializer should be created and initialized on every function entry. A static with an initializer should only be initialized once, during the execution setup, before main() is given control (just as a global would be). I have had local statics get reinitialized on each function entry as though they were automatics, which is incorrect. Test your own compiler to be sure.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about a function declaring a global. Do you mean as an `extern`?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield: I'm not sure what part of my post your asking about, but I was referring to the OP's two examples - the first, an inherently global definition and the second, a local static.